# Spring MVC return modelandView class

Tags: java, spring

```
return new ModelAndView( ? , "listBooks", listBooks);
```

at place `?` I want to return a class=> `net.codejava.spring.PDFBuilder`. Is it possible if yes then how?

Comment: `return new ModelAndView(PDFBuilder.class, "listBooks", listBooks);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to pass the class. The constructor is:

```
ModelAndView(View view, String modelName, Object modelObject)
```

You can supply PDFBuilder object since it is a successor of View but you need to use an Object and not the class.

```
return new ModelAndView( myPdfBuilderObject , "listBooks", listBooks);
```